# Attempt at utilizing decodable

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to create decodable structs for the JSON that I am receiving, but I keep getting:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "inquiry_quantity", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "orders", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys...

This is the JSON that I am running through my decoder:

```
{
    "orders_important": 2,
    "orders_inquiry": 2,
    "orders": [

    {
        "information": {
            "total_price": 12.0,
            "order_stage": "CONFIRMED",
            "total_cases": 333,
            "scanned": false,
            "inquiry": false,
            "foodhub": "shdw.fh1@agg.com",
            "identifier": "GPO00024",
            "delivery_date": "2019-11-04"
        },
        "details": {
            "pack_size": "40#",
            "cases": 333,
            "plu_code": 12434,
            "crop_plan": 1633,
            "commodity": "Conventional Bananas, , 40#"
        }
    },
    {
        "information": {
            "inquiree": "FARMER",
            "total_price": 23.5,
            "order_stage": "INQUIRY",
            "inquiry_quantity": 0,
            "total_cases": 56,
            "scanned": false,
            "inquiry": true,
            "foodhub": "shdw.fh1@agg.com",
            "inquiry_type": "PRICE",
            "identifier": "GPO00027",
            "inquiry_price": 26.5,
            "delivery_date": "2019-11-05",
            "inquiry_details": "You have requested $26.5 per case, instead of $23.5."
        },
        "details": {
            "pack_size": "40#",
            "cases": 12,
            "plu_code": 12434,
            "crop_plan": 1589,
            "commodity": "Conventional Bananas, , 40#"
        }
    },
],
"orders_count": 4
}
```

My decodable structs: (EDIT: Removed Init)

```
struct OrderBundle: Decodable{
    let orders_important : Int
    let orders_inquiry:Int
    let orders_count: Int
    let orders: [Order]
}

struct Order: Decodable {
    let inquiry_quantity : Int
    let inquiry_price : Int
    let inquiry_info : String
    let price : Int
    let cropPlan : Int
    let identifier: String
    let deliveryDate : String
    let quantity : Int
    let unit : String
    let status : String
    let destination : String
    let commodity: String

}
```

And lastly calling my decoder:

```
let orderData = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode(OrderBundle.self, from: data!)
                print(orderData)
```

I have tried it with and without the Init in my Orders and both ways I am still getting the same error.

Comment: `init(json:)` won't be called by `JSONDecoder().decode(OrderBundle.self, from: data!)`, you know that? You need to add a custom init with coder to handle the same.

Comment: I just realized how that wouldn't work out. How do I go about writing a custom init? Would I have to run another decoder within the custom init?

Comment: The issue here is that none of the fields of `Order` appear directly inthe json. THey're nested within two sub-objected, keyed by `"information"` and `"details"`. You either need to make an `OrderInformation` and `OrderDetails` struct, or you need to write a custom initializer that parses that data out to populate directly into your `Order`. https://medium.com/@nictheawesome/using-codable-with-nested-json-is-both-easy-and-fun-19375246c9ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that any dictionary must be decoded to an extra struct if `init(from decoder` is not provided. So basically the structure of the model must be

```
struct OrderBundle: Decodable {
    struct Information : Decodable {
    struct Details : Decodable {
```

The complete structs are as follows, many struct members must be declared as optional and `inquiryPrice` is `Double`, not `Int`. `convertFromSnakeCase` converts the *snaked_cased* keys to *camelCased* struct members.

```
struct OrderBundle : Decodable{
    let ordersImportant : Int
    let ordersInquiry : Int
    let ordersCount : Int
    let orders : [Order]
}

struct Order : Decodable {

    let information : Information
    let details : Details

    struct Information : Decodable {
        let inquiryQuantity : Int?
        let inquiryPrice : Double?
        let inquiryInfo : String?
        let price : Int?
        let cropPlan : Int?
        let identifier : String
        let deliveryDate : String
        let quantity : Int?
        let unit : String?
        let status : String?
        let destination : String?
        let commodity: String?
    }

    struct Details : Decodable {
        let packSize : String
        let cases : Int
        let pluCode : Int
        let cropPlan : Int
        let commodity : String
    }
}
```

And the code to decode it

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let orderData = try decoder.decode(OrderBundle.self, from: data!)
print(orderData)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try out this solution and then learn more about decoder inits and CodingKeys moving forward. I better understand the structure. However, I am getting `Type 'OrderBundle' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` with this method which I don't see what has changed.

Comment: Please use exactly my structs and add the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy

Comment: This is great. Thank you again @vadian